# javascript to open / close submenu not working with <input> and <label> in the mix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to recreate a responsive mobile menu that has the following html:

```
<ul id="mobileNav">
     <li class="toggle"><a href="#canvas" id="mobile-close-nav" class="icon-close"></a></li>
     <li class="folder">
           <input type="checkbox" name="mobile-folder-toggle" id="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-box hidden">
           <label for="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">About</label>
           <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
     </li>
     <li class="folder">
           <input type="checkbox" name="mobile-folder-toggle" id="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-box hidden">
           <label for="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">About</label>Products</label>
           <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">First</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I am using the below script to open / close the submenu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.sub-menu').hide();
 $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
        $("ul",this).toggle();
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

but it's not working for me with the "input" and "label" in the mix. It works when the below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile-folder-toggle" id="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-box hidden">
           <label for="mobile-folder-toggle" class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">About</label>
```

is changed to this:

```
<a class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">About</a>
```

("input" is removed, and "label" is changed to "a")
but I need it to work as per the original code, because the input/label combo needs to be there to control something else. How do I modify the script so it works?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using the snippet functionality of stack overflow to make this a working example. Or at least explain what you mean by "it's not working"

Comment: So listen to the onchange of the input instead of the click.

Comment: by "it's not working" I mean the script to open / close the submenu does not open / close the submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I tried to make it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.sub-menu').hide();
 $(".folder-toggle-box").change(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mobileNav">
     <li class="toggle"><a href="#canvas" id="mobile-close-nav" class="icon-close"></a></li>
     <li class="folder">
           <input type="checkbox" name="mobile-folder-toggle" id="mobile-folder-toggle1" class="folder-toggle-box hidden">
           <label for="mobile-folder-toggle1" class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">About</label>
           <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
     </li>
     <li class="folder">
           <input type="checkbox" name="mobile-folder-toggle" id="mobile-folder-toggle2" class="folder-toggle-box hidden">
           <label for="mobile-folder-toggle2" class="folder-toggle-label" data-href="#">Products</label>
           <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">First</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                    <li class="page-collection"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just have to prevent the event from bubbling. Just add return false like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.sub-menu').hide();
 $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
        $("ul",this).toggle();
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Or add event.preventDefault();

Comment: thanks, but I need the "input+label" event to work, because clicking on it triggers a change in the icon after the parent li from "+" to "-" to indicate the expanding/contracting of the submenu